# Boot/repair problem

Tags: boot, grub2

I am attempting to repair a new Ubuntu 15.10 installation with Boot-repair. This is a standard non-UEFI installation. I installed Boot-repair onto the Ubuntu 15.10 Live CD and started it.  When I run the "Recommended Repair" from Boot-repair I get the following message after a minute or so:

"Please close all your package managers (Software Center, Update Manager, Synaptic, ...) ... Then try again."

It does not appear that the boot configuration is changed and this will repeat forever. So far as I can tell after checking with ps, I have no package managers open. Can anyone explain what is going on and what should I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Repair GRUB boot loader with a built-in tool.
Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Select Try Ubuntu without installing.
On Live desktop open a terminal.
Execute these commands :

```
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt  
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sd*
```

Note : `sd*` = disk | `sd**` = system partition

Use GParted to identify the partition numbers.
It is included in the Ubuntu installation media.